# Json sent from android to php defaults to index.php

Tags: php, android, json

I am new to PHP. I have an android app that sends JSON string to `myphp.php` but it gets redirected to `index.php`. Is this normal behavior? How can I go around that?

Code

```
URL url= null;
HttpURLConnection urlConn;
url = new URL ("http://192.***.*.**/myserver/myphp.php");
urlConn = (HttpURLConnection)updateurl.openConnection();
```

This is the content of myphp.php.

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
        //include '/index.php';

        $json = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $decoded = json_decode($json, TRUE);
        $lat = $decoded['lat'];
        $lon = $decoded['lon'];

        sendID($pasid, $lat, $lon);

        function sendID($tokenid, $lat, $lon) {
//request url
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

//your api key
        $apiKey = 'key';

//payload data
        $data = array('lat' => $lat, 'lon' => $lon);
        //$registration_ids = array($tokenid);
        $message_Id = "0000001";

        $fields = array('to' => $tokenid, 'data' => $data);

//http header
        $headers = array('Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
        'Content-Type: application/json');

//curl connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        curl_error($ch); //see the error details
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        echo $result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below method, but with `namevaluepairs` and it was working. If your php is configured well, it won't redirect to index file. Can you share the `myphp.php` file contents?

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.***.*.**/myserver/myphp.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Also try to open myphp.php from your browser.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have included myphp.php file content now. I also run it in my browser but it is redirecting to index.php as well.

Comment: @quantum droid: still problem persists??

Comment: url = new URL ("http://192.***.*.**/myserver/myphp.php");
urlConn = (HttpURLConnection)updateurl.openConnection(); 

You declared your myphp.php URL as 'url' and opening connection with   "updateurl" ?????